# Bootstrap btn-link vertical alignment slightly out

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When placing a Bootstrap 3 button with class `btn-link` in a block of text, the vertical alignment seems to be out by a few pixels:

```
<div>Foo<button class="btn btn-link">Button</button>Bar</div>
```

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1cLu5nz/2/)

How can I fix this? Removing the padding from the button improves the issue somewhat, but I'm still seeing a discrepancy of a few pixels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to fix this would be to wrap the text nodes with `<span>` elements and then modify the [`vertical-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/st5a1mae/)

```
div span {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```
<div>
    <span>Foo</span>
    <button class="btn btn-link">Button</button>
    <span>Bar</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can't) wrap all non-button items within `<span>`'s, a simpler approach may be to change the `btn-link`'s vertical-alignment from `middle` to `baseline.`

```
.btn-link { vertical-align: baseline; }
```

Quoting from [**CSS-Tricks.com:** *"What is Vertical Align?"*](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)

> The default value of vertical-align (if you declare nothing), is baseline. Images will line up with the text at the baseline of the text. Note that descenders on letters dip below the baseline. Images don't line up with the lowest point of the descenders, that isn't the baseline.
>
> [image: Vertical baseline example from CSS-Tricks.com]

Comment: Be sure to set padding-top and padding-bottom to 0 as well or the button will be too tall vertically and your line height will be off.